# Is it more grammatically correct to use five-point star or five-pointed star?

Tags: differences

Possibly this is a contextual situation - I've seen it both ways, and if there are any rules regarding this I'd like to know them.

Comment: I'm rather surprised that 'five-pointed star' seems the more common even in the States ([GoogleNgrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=five-point+star%2Cfive-pointed+star&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfive%20-%20point%20star%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfive%20-%20pointed%20star%3B%2Cc0)).  The Americans usually go for the punchier (more pointed?) variant. [This site](http://www.religionfacts.com/five-point-star) uses both variants.

Comment: What differences d'you see between *a five-pointed star* and *a five-point plan*, please?

Comment: I don't see much difference. I naturally used five-point star and someone changed it, though they aren't as familiar with grammar as I, so checked into it and found what you did, that five-pointed star seems to be more used. Just wondering if I'm missing something.